# How to distinguish between a SHA1 string and a date-time string?

Tags: php

Basically I have two options:

```
$one = "fdfeb16f096983ada02db49d46a8154475d700ae";
$two = "2011-12-28 05:20:01";
```

I need some sort of regex, so that I can detect wether the string follows the pattern in `$one`, or the pattern in `$two`

Detect if the string is sha1 or datetime.

What would be the best way to determine this?

Thanks

Comment: "$one" is simply a[n all-lower case] hex string with a fixed length. If you *tried* something you would already have an answer. (Like `[a-fA-F0-9]{40}`.) Depending on what is done with "$two", I would be tempted to covert it to a date/time and reject it if that failed, although a regex for that is relatively trivial. Again, it would be already be solved if you *tried* something.

Comment: @pst - yeah I did try something, I had something along the lines of `/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/i` - I don't know why you'd include A-F in your regex when you can simply use `i` to do case-insensitive. I was merely seeking a better way to do it. Thanks for your presumption.

Comment: @Latox, presumptions aside, it's a good idea to post what you've tried and what did and didn't work. SO is full of lazy questions, and people tend to assume the worst. Showing your work helps us better answer your question anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If you are **ABSOLUTE** sure those are the **ONLY** two options, I would go with strlen, and not some kind of marvelous regexp.
Even if those are not the only two options (user messed up), I would still go with strlen, and then check specifically for each format, if it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: It's not a complex problem. I do not see an advantage for just a string length for "$one" in this case over a simple detect-if-sha1.

Comment: @pst My way of thinking is any problem you can solve with a straight forward function (strlen/isset/strpos/count etc) is a better approach then a reg-exp, which is harder to maintain, and probably (although insignificant in most cases) slower. For example the length and/or count of an array/string are cached in the zval => very chip to get those values.

Comment: I don't see any maintenance scenarios in which the length check is superior, but several where it's inferior (e.g. the format changes, or another format is added). I'd add that having "absolutely" and "only" in all-caps bold strongly suggests this isn't the best solution. Why make assumptions when it's easy not to? With the regex, you can at least log an error if the input is unexpected.

Comment: @Isaac Cambron Analyze the problem, anticipate the range possible inputs that may come in in the future, design the solution accordingly. Using canons for every problems is not always good.

Comment: I basically agree with that sentiment, but we seem to disagree on the complexity and heaviweightness of regexes. To me, they're a basic but powerful part of the toolkit that every programmer should wield with confidence, not some arcane device for exotic situations. It's not a cannon, just a more accurate hand gun. Perfect for stuff like this.

Comment: @Isaac Cambron I agree on your first sentence :-) and it it is a vey targeted solution. And it is OK. Coding style is not exact science .

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to apply regexes in PHP, but assuming the actual regexes are enough...

```
/^[a-f0-9]{40}$/
```

Match 40 characters of consisting of a-f or 0-9. The ^ and $ match the beginning and end of the string, so nothing else can be in it.

```
/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/
```

Match strings with the date pattern you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match($one, $string) {
    echo "$string matches $one";
} else if (preg_match($two, $string) {
    echo "$string matches $two";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the preg_match() function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Conditionals with regex to match each of the options.  For the second case:

```
if(preg_match('|(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|',$two)
{
   echo "Matching two";
}
```

I don't see a clear pattern for number one, but you could do elseif(s) to detect other potential cases.